# Cannot bind shortcut to diodon history menu although it works from terminal

Tags: bash, shortcut-keys

Diodion hotkey feature doesn't work for me. So I wanted to bind system hotkey to `/usr/bin/diodon` to open the history menu.

If I type `/usr/bin/diodon` in bash shell, it works absolutely fine, the menu opens.

If I bind `bash -c "/usr/bin/diodon"` or run a script below, the script is executed but no history menu opens.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/diodon
exit 0
```

How is this even possible? Am I missing something?

Comment: Indeed it does not work. A bug on the issue is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/diodon/+bug/1630375

Comment: @vanadium You found the solution! Thank you, Sir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried [the workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/diodon/+bug/1630375/comments/6) @vanadium has found and adding delay to solve race condition worked for me (Xubuntu 16.04.3):

`bash -c "sleep 0.1 && diodon"`

Comment: It would appear easier to directly insert following command as "command" in the shortcut key dialog: `sh -c "sleep 0.1s && diodon`. Please try that and if that also works (which it should) then please edit your answer and instead replace it with this way more elegant appoach. If it would not work immediately, then try increasing the delay by changing `0.1` to `0.2` etc. Please add also your current Ubuntu version. It may not work on all desktops as discussed in the thread I linked to.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Done. Thank you again!